# cannot visit subdomain from front end

Tags: subdomain

I have created a subdomain in plesk 10.4 and it created the default files as usual. I uploaded my site files to the subdomain's file directory and when i click *preview website in browser* in the plesk panel i can see the site (mostly).

However, when I visit the new subdomain (`dev.tradelabels.com`) in my browser directly I get 'Oops! Google Chrome could not find dev.tradelabels.com'. I have read other questions on here and other in forums about similar issues but the fixes didn't work for me.

I tried to *switch on DNS service* for the subdomain but that didn't change anything.
In my experience with creating subdomains in cPanel you just click *create subdomain*, give it a name and you're up and running. I heard some people say that the DNS entry has to propagate but that doesn't sound right to me as we are dealing with subdomains not TLDs.

Am I not aware of an extra step when creating subdomains in plesk?
I read the user guide but it says nothing different than what I'm doing.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P4 <<>> dev.tradelabels.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 3881
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

**`status: NXDOMAIN`** <--- Your domain name does not exist in DNS.
Your web browser has no idea what server to talk to unless you create a DNS entry for `dev.tradelabels.com`.

Your DNS appears to be handled by Amazon's Route 53 service. Go there, create an appropriate DNS entry, and things will work.  If you are unclear on how to do this you will need to contact Amazon's technical support.